Heroku Golang api with some python callouts
I have a heroku golang 'app' thats deploying fine. The issue is that it calls some python scripts as the result of some REST requests. I have a requirements.txt in my /bin (python) dir but I'm wondering if it's possible to have the golang deploy process also process pip3 python3 requirements when I git push heroku master? Is this possible in a Procfile? Thanks!

I used the instructions here and executed the following commands:
heroku buildpacks:clear
heroku buildpacks:add heroku/go
heroku buildpacks:add heroku/python

I then moved my requirements.txt into my top level, leaving all my python scripts in /bin.
